# Is it possible to create an Asp.Net C# application without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am curious to know whether it is possible to create an Asp.Net C# application without Visual Studio.
If possible means what is the best way to do it?

---

I've googled it but ended up not getting any clear idea over it.
I am just a Begginer only,any help in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: The big question is: Why don't you want to use Visual Studio? The Express version is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing ASP.NET C# applications in Visual Studio, some developer used text editor UltraEdit32.

Assuming you have the correct assemblies and a C# compiler you in theory can use whatever you want to edit the code and then just run the compiler by hand or using a build script. That being said it is a real pain doing .NET development without Visual Studio/SharpEdit/Monodevelop in my opinion.

Comment: So what I've understood is like--- we can write our code and edit them in the text editor(UltraEdit), for compilation and running the appropriate .net framework is needed. No need of entire Visual Studio all???????

Comment: The only thign required is the .net framework which also ships the compiler. But as Sunil mentioned, it's a pain without a good IDE.

Answer (score 2):

If you want create application/portal in Asp.Net, you must required VS. However you can run the built solution/files from the .Net Framework only. For creating/editing you need VS Editor and for compilation/running you need framework according to versions. When you install VS, it installs framework, editor and other necessary objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do it?

If the reason is the cost you can use the express editions. Especially the Express for Web. Take a look on [this link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can !, But you will be missing many thing that is provide only in VS (or VS express).

You can install the Webmatrix 3 (in Win7,8). Webmatrix will help you to create website using ASP.NET, Nodejs,PHP without anything required.

In case of you you will be got panic but practically it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use mono develop for that. http://monodevelop.com/

Answer (score 0):

Free tools such as [Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com) and [SharpDevelop](http://sharpdevelop.net) can be used to create ASP.NET MVC applications. They don't have a WSIWG designer for WebForms, so it would be rather difficult for you to code such projects in them.

You can even use Notepad and Windows SDK to do so, but I don't think that's going to be quick and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can create an solution without Visual studio. But need the following things.

- Get the template for the asp.net application or you can create by
  own, but need to modify the project file.
- Use the inbuilt framework
  (installed in your machine) compiler (csc or vbc) to compile the
  application and convert to executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webmatrix in Win7/8. But you will feel uncomfortable if you will not use Visual Studio.
Because only Visual Studio provides the necessary tools and other feature that are required to make the application.
You can go for Visual Studio Express, because its free.